# "RNCWebView" was not found in the UI Manager

Tags: reactjs, react-native

My current project requires to install react-native-chartjs and react-native-canvas..react-native-chartjs is making use of react-native-webview@2.0.0, while react-native-canvas requires a different version of react-native-webview - react-native-webview@10.0.0
It's returning the following error - [image]
Now what should I do...both are required dependencies for my proj

Answer (score 1):

Try this for RN 0.60 and higher

add to podfile

```
pod 'react-native-webview', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-webview'
```

Then

```
cd ios && pod install
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found the same issue already, by following the Pod install as solved completly the problem.

Go to IOS folder and RUN Pod install.

Thanks